# Add thread to Main Thread Process in TPL

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, threadpool

We have a list of subscriptions and we are running thread for every subscription. It's long-running process.

We are fetching subscriptions list and running thread for every subscription. We want to run new thread for newly added subscriptions without stopping old threads.

We don't want to add list of subscription into an array or list and track from that. I'm looking for better alternative to that. Every subscription thread is not linked to each other.

We want to use TPL library or TPL dataflow if possible.[image]

Comment: How many subscriptions do you expect in total? One thread per subscriptions sounds like one thread per socket which isn't a good solution because of different reasons.

Comment: @user743414 Right now we are not considering a numbers of limit thread per CPU .

Comment: I wanted to wrote one "thread per connection". :) The issue in general with one thread per connection or whatever is stack memory. Let a threadpool with a given number of threads to work on the subscriptions isn't an option?